# [osgEarth]* [Horizon] No horizon info installed in callback

Tags: omnet++, osgearth

I've recently updated to OMNeT++ 5.4 from 5.1.1.
Since the switch, our project (which was originally based on the osg-earth example) is accompanied by the following error:

```
[osgEarth]* [Horizon] No horizon info installed in callback
[osgEarth]* [Horizon] No horizon info installed in callback
[osgEarth]* [Horizon] No horizon info installed in callback
[osgEarth]* [Horizon] No horizon info installed in callback
...
```

The message is thrown to the console at a high frequency as long as the simulation is executed. It doesn't seem to effect the execution but can't be good and I'd love to resolve this.

How can we solve the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ 5.4 uses a newer version of osgEarth. This is a defect in osgEarth that was fixed in a later version.

https://github.com/gwaldron/osgearth/issues/815

Depending on what platform you are on, you may try to update the osgEarth libraries to see whether that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rudi. To know that this is not an issue I need to fix in my project is good enough for now. Best!